# Am unable to read the date field from excel file selenium reads the date as Col=9=43070 Col=10=43070 Col=11=42931 Col=12=43296

Tags: excel, selenium

Selenium is incorrectly reading the date as `43095` when I enter  `26-12-2017`. How to get Selenium to read the correct date?

```
for (int i=0;i<=TcRow;i++) 
{
    for (int j=0;j<TcCol;j++) 
    {
        Cell Cell=TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
    }
}
```

Am I reading the format incorrectly?

```
TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

What changes do I need to do here to make sure they read both the string and the date field?

```
data[i][j]=TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue during reading the excel file where I'm fetching date is formatted in dd/mm/yyyy format and selenium fetching wrong value.

For that, I have used `DataFormatter`. It will returns Excel cell value with format e.g.  Date format 15-04-208 in excellent then it will returns date with same format. Look below code that I used in my Framework. Hope it will also work for you.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path\\to\\file.xlsx"); 
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(worksheet);

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum);
    String cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    System.out.println(cellValue);
    return cellValue;
```

Let me know if you have any query.